# Does externally owned account have two parameters ("codehash" and "storage root")?

Tags: storage

I often see the following figure.

That figure explains to me that every contract account has four parameters for computing the global state root.

But I can't understand what parameters the externally owned account has for calculating the global state root.

I think the user's account should have two parabeters(nonce and balances) at least.

[image]

I'm sorry that I'm not good at writing English.

Thank you for your reading effort about my question.

---

editing ...

I find the answer from the website "https://medium.com/@preethikasireddy/how-does-ethereum-work-anyway-22d1df506369".

That says

[The account state consists of four components, which are present regardless of the type of account:]

Comment: Since you found the answer, please add it as an answer to this question so that it is easier for others to find.

Comment: For externally owned accounts the code or storage is zero. It doesn't need code or storage, yes. They exist so we don't need 2 different data structures imo

Comment: I answer my own question. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I can doulbe-check my answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the answer from the website "https://medium.com/@preethikasireddy/how-does-ethereum-work-anyway-22d1df506369".

That says

[The account state consists of four components, which are present regardless of the type of account:]

and also says that

storageRoot is empty by default and the codeHash field is the hash of the empty string.

This means all of the externally owned account may have the same value about codehash.